# Presto - can I do alter table if exists?

Tags: presto

How can I alter table name only if exists?

Something like: `alter table mydb.myname if exists rename to mydb.my_new_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE users RENAME TO people;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.myname RENAME TO mydb.my_new_name;
```

Please notice that `IF EXISTS` syntax is not available here. Please find more informations here: https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/sql/alter-table.html The work for that is tracked under: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/2260
Currently you need to handle this on a different layer, like java program that is running SQL queries to Presto over JDBC.

Comment: I know how to do alter table but wanted to cover a situation when I try to alter a table that does not exist, to avoid failing ETLs.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer this is not currently possible. I created an issue in the Presto project for that. See https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/2260